# django queryset select all from multiple tables

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I want to select all columns from multiple table join using django queryset corresponding to following sql

```
select user.*, address.*, contact.* from user left join address on user.id = address.userid left join contact on user.id = contact.userid
```

I have following python
`User.objects.values()` to get all user data.
`User.objects.values(first_name, last_name, contacts__number, addresses__zip)` to get specific columns

But I dont know how to get all columns from all 3 tables something like

```
User.objects.values(*, contacts__*, addressess__*)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined the `ForeignKey` relationships on the `User` class, you can use:

```
users = User.objects.select_related("Address", "Contact").all()
```

Then you can access the related object on the `User` object as as attribute:

```
for user in users:
    print(user.address)
    print(user.contact)
```

Actually, the `select_related()` hint is not necessary and you can access the related record as an attribute in any case, it just prevents a separate database query for every access.

If you are using the `User` model in the Django auth app, you can go either of these routes to achieve your goal:

- Attach a model as the profile to DJango `User` model:
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model
- Substitute the default `User` model with a model of your own: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model
- Use "reverse" relationship queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: foreign_key is in Contact and Address models referring to User and not in User model so its returning Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'contacts' 'addresses'

Comment: yeah I know I can use attributes to access reverse relationship which is also mentioned in problem above however I want to use '*' access to access all attributes without specifying each.